# Calculate a parent div's width by the amount of child divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am currently creating a horizontal image slider which will be used more than once with different amount of images.
At the moment, the parent div needs to be bigger than 100% to fit all images in, so I calculate the width by adding all widths of the child divs (which include the images) manually in a calculator and then add it to the css, but I want to be able to calculate it automatically with the help of either CSS or JS/jQuery.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    let images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.bild')];
    let slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
    let sliderWidth;
    let imageWidth;
    let current = 0;
    let target = 0;
    let ease = .05;

    window.addEventListener('resize', init);

    function lerp(start, end, t){
        return start * (1-t) + end * t;
    }
    function setTransform (el, transform){
        el.style.transform = transform;
    }
    function init(){
        sliderWidth = slider.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        imageWidth = sliderWidth / images.length;
        document.body.style.height = `${sliderWidth - (window.innerWidth - window.innerHeight)}px`
    }

    function animate(){
        current = parseFloat(lerp(current, target, ease)).toFixed(2);
        target = window.scrollY;
        setTransform(slider, `translateX(-${current}px)`);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    init();
    animate();
    console.log(sliderWidth)
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3900px; /* this should be calculated automatically by the amount of divs with the class "item" multiplied by the item width */
  height: 100%;
}
.slider-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 455px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #13271b;
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 435px;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  border: none;
}

/* example "images" */
#one, #four {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
#two, #five {
  background-color: #222222;
}
#three, #six {
  background-color: #777777;;
}

#zero {
  background-color: #ee2277;;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider-inner">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" id="zero">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" id="one">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" >
                <div class="image" id="two">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" id="three">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" id="four">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" id="five">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="image" id="six">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
/** @param {HTMLElement} sliderEl */
function scaleSlider(sliderEl) {
    let totalWidth = 0;
    sliderEl.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach(item => totalWidth += item.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    sliderEl.style.width = `${totalWidth}px`;
}
```

Comment: Where do I need to put the code? Should I delete something aswell? When I put it in my .js file, it just does nothing at all.

Comment: Run it on each `.slider` element on the page , e.g: `document.querySelectorAll('.slider').forEach(scaleSlider)`.  Each element will only consider the items within it when computing the overall width.

Comment: now it seems to work, thank you!

Comment: I got one more question, I want to add one item at the start and the end with a different width to create some blank space, how can I add those towards the totalWidth of the slider? (Like when the item has an ID of "blank" or something like that)

Comment: Assuming the padding element has a class of `.item` then it will be included in the overall width calculation.  How the content of that item is populated (i.e. whether it has an image or is just used for spacing) can be managed independently.

Comment: Alternatively, the query in the `scaleSlider` function can be changed to a group selector of `.item, .blank` to include elements with either class, and keep the image items separate.  It really depends on your use case.  Note here that a _class_ of blank is used rather than an _ID_ since there may be multiple blanks in a slider.